# Testing x days from now with timecop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an `account` model which has the `trial_ends_at` field to which I would like to set `30.days.from_now` when the user creates the account.

I'm using `RSpec` and `timecop` to test the trial period, but haven't been able to do so.

#### Progress till now

```rb
it "sets the trial_ends_at to 30 days from now" do
  post admin_accounts_path, params: { account: { name: "My company", subdomain: "example" } }

  Timecop.freeze(Time.zone.today + 30) do
    expect(Account.first.trial_ends_at).to eq(30.days.from_now)
  end
end
```

The test does not pass.

#### Alternately, I also tried

```rb
it "sets the trial_ends_at to 30 days from now" do
  post admin_accounts_path, params: { account: { name: "My company", subdomain: "example" } }

  Timecop.freeze(Time.zone.today + 30) do
    expect(Account.first.on_generic_trial?).to be_truthy
  end
end
```

This test is brittle. It passes for `30.days.from_now` and it fails if the trial is set lower than that, but passes if the trial is set higher than that, for eg: `50.days.from_now`.

The `on_generic_trial?` method is from the [pay](https://github.com/pay-rails/pay) gem.

Comment: By the way, in newer Rails versions you can accomplish this without Timecop :-)

Comment: @FrankGroeneveld Can you share your solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is something like: create account and set `trial_ends_at = Time.now + 30 days` then move ahead to next month then try to expect that `trial_ends_at` is equal to the next of next month, so it failed. Let try:

```rb
it "sets the trial_ends_at to 30 days from now" do
  Timecop.freeze(Time.zone.today) do
    post admin_accounts_path, params: { account: { name: "My company", subdomain: "example" } }
    expect(Account.first.trial_ends_at).to eq(30.days.from_now)
  end
end
```